# collapse and expand tabs jquery / simple accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have query regarding Accordion tabs ..

I have used **Accordion Menu** plugin Below code i have used for the tabs in the page .

```
  [accordions]
  [accordion title ="about"]**Content 1** [/accordion ]
  [accordion title="Home"]**Content 2** [/accordion ]
  [/accordions]
```

The web page looks like as follows:

[image]

I want first both these tabs to be collapsed and.When clicked on **ABOUT** it should expand and display the content .And once clicked on **Home** it should collapse **ABOUT** tab and expand the home page

By jquery i can achieve this but i dont know which script to download and work with it..

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance

Comment: There could have been options for collapsing/expanding the accordion. An accordion plugin is collapsible and expandable by nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two different methods for simple accordion; 1st with close button, 2nd is with hover trigger.

**1)** Here is [JsFiddle example with **close** button:](http://jsfiddle.net/gWcFD/66/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('.content').slideUp(400);//reset panels

$('.panel').click(function() {//open
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id');//takes id from clicked ele
   $('#'+takeID+'C').slideDown(400);
                             //show's clicked ele's id macthed div = 1second
});
$('span').click(function() {//close
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id').replace('Close','');
   //strip close from id = 1second
    $('#'+takeID+'C').slideUp(400);//hide clicked close button's panel
});​
```

**html:**

```
<div class="panel" id="panel1">panel1</div>
<div id="panel1C">content1
  <span id="panel1Close">X</span>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel2">panel2</div>
<div id="panel2C">content2
  <span id="panel2Close">X</span>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel3">panel3</div>
<div id="panel3C">content3
  <span id="panel3Close">X</span>
</div>
```

### -------

​
**2)** Here is [JsFiddle example with **hover** trigger:](http://jsfiddle.net/gWcFD/68/)

```
$('.panel').hover(function() {
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id');//takes id from clicked ele
   $('.content').stop(false,true).slideUp(400);//close
   //used stop for prevent conflict
   $('#'+takeID+'C').stop(false,true).slideDown(400);//open
   //show's clicked ele's id macthed div
});​
```

Comment: hi barlas..thanks ..since i am doing it in wordpress (cms)  so i need it in  php and not html....:(..
That is wht i exactly want... ..but in my case the content 1 ,content 2, are the pages of the wordpress....

sorry my mistake didnt mention it earlier..

Comment: what are iframes?and  i l have to write the page ids ??

Comment: wait untill page loads and inspect inside panels

Comment: these are pages from the net right ("http://hurriyet.com")?so in case if i create 3 pages(about,home,peoples)..in wordpress then in this case what is to be done?

Comment: i am having difficulties to understand your real question.. if you dont want to create new pages, use default html tags inside your div.contents

Answer (score 0):

In case you use jQuery UI Accordion, you can add simple event to your accordion.

or add event:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "accordioncreate", function(event, ui) {
  $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", -1 )
});
```