# how can I collapse a specific part of an accordion styled on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

I have got links from several pages linking to a specific page where my accordion grid is. And on page load I want the target part of the accordion grid to collapse automatically for the user.

Take for example: Page A and Page B. Page A is where the user is coming from to view something on Page B. Page B has an accordion with 4 (e.g 1,2,3 & 4) parts. If the user click on link 2 from Page A to Page B, the number 2 part of the accordion should collapse for the user to see.

Find below the codes:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="accord_bar">
<ul id="accordion">
<li><a href="#recent" class="heading">Number 1 Header</a>
<ul id="recent"><li>Number 1</li></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#popular" class="heading">Number 2 Header</a>
<ul id="recent"><li>Number 2</li></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#categories" class="heading">Number 3 Header</a>
<ul id="recent"><li>Number 3</li></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#archive" class="heading">Number 4 Header</a>
<ul id="recent"><li>Number 4</li></ul>
</li></ul></div>
```

**Javascipt in the HEAD tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#accordion').accordion(
    {active: "a.default", header: "a.heading"}
    );
});
```

**Linked accordion Jquery file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-accordion.js"></script>
```

I really need to fix this asap and I will be very grateful if anyone can help...

Comment: on page load, can you read document.location.href.split('#')[1] and use ().trigger('click') on a matching element (or conversely, collapse them all by default and 'open' the matching element, which is what I think you mean).

Comment: Working on your example: you want Page B to be responsive to Page A, like when a user comes from Page A to Page B, the accordion from Page B displays a specific slide, and when a user comes from, let's say Page C to Page B, the same accordion from Page B displays a different slide, like when coming from Page A?

Answer (score 0):

You can built your own simple accorion with jQuery, no need ui.

For collapsing a specific part of an accordion with [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method with this simple accordion structure.

[**Here is jsFiddle with hover trigger.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWcFD/68/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('.content').slideUp(100);
$('.content').eq(1).slideDown(600);
//for collapsing second part of an accordion

$('.panel').hover(function() {//open
    var takeID = $(this).attr('id');//takes id from clicked ele
    $('.content').stop(false,true).slideUp(600);
    //used stop for prevent conflict
    $('#'+takeID+'C').stop(false,true).slideDown(600);
    ///show's hovered ele's id macthed div
});​
```

**html:**

```
<div class="panel" id="panel1">panel1</div>
<div class="content" id="panel1C">content1</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel2">panel2</div>
<div class="content" id="panel2C">content2</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel3">panel3</div>
<div class="content" id="panel3C">content3</div>
```

### ----------

[**Here is jsFiddle with click trigger and close button.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWcFD/69/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('.content').slideUp(100);
$('.content').eq(1).slideDown(600);
//for collapsing second part of an accordion

$('.panel').click(function() {//open
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id');//takes id from clicked ele
   $('#'+takeID+'C').slideDown(600);//show's clicked ele's id macthed div
});
$('span').click(function() {//close
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id').replace('Close','');//strip close from id
   $('#'+takeID+'C').slideUp(600);//hide clicked close button's panel
});​
```

**html:**

```
<div class="panel" id="panel1">panel1</div>
<div class="content" id="panel1C">content1<span id="panel1Close">X</span></div>

<div class="panel" id="panel2">panel2</div>
<div class="content" id="panel2C">content2<span id="panel2Close">X</span></div>

<div class="panel" id="panel3">panel3</div>
<div class="content" id="panel3C">content3<span id="panel3Close">X</span></div>
```

Note: I've answered accordion related this answer before:
[collapse and expand tabs jquery / simple accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504193/collapse-and-expand-tabs-jquery-simple-accordion/11504398#11504398)