# page jumps to top after closing div jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have some accordion layers unfolding when you click them. If I close one layer the page always jumps to the top? Is there a way of preventing this? Thanks

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc58K/

Comment: Your page scrolls to the top because the page is no longer taller than the viewport, therefore the scrollbar disappears.

Comment: for a different jQuery accordion structure, you can inspect this way also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173658/how-can-i-collapse-a-specific-part-of-an-accordion-styled-on-page-load/12173834#12173834

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when page's height decrease. Try to add height to the body:

```
body { height:2000px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qc58K/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works.. but if I then have a footer on the page it will be way down there.. ?

Comment: Wouldn't `min-height` be a better choice?

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for suggestion but it won't create big difference on this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc58K/2/

Comment: @MarcusSilverman if your page is longer than on your accordion, you don't need to add height. I just wrote `height:2000` for this example. And **note that you should define accordion container's height too, for preventing animate bugs with element above and lover it.** See this example, loverEle is moving when accordion panel clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc58K/3 if you define height to the accordion container, it won't move.