# Both tr and td clickable and should trigger different actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a table each column is clickable and reveals some content when clicked. Besides each column has a td which holds a button to hide the column. Like this

[image]

The hide part does not work for me. Obviously the reveal part is triggered first and hide is ignored/not fired.

```
$("tr td.remove").live("click", function(){
    $(this).parent("tr:first").hide('slow');
});

$(".reveal").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

HTML

```
 <table>
    <tr class="reveal">
       <td>300,00 €</td>
       <td class="remove">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
        <td colspan="2">
           Content
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

How can I combine this to accept both actions? I use jQuery 1.6.2.

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2jVtC/1/

Comment: include html to your question please.

Comment: Help us help you; put it in a jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2jVtC/17/)

```
$('.content').hide();
$(".reveal").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle("fast");
});
$("tr td.remove").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parent("tr").slideUp('slow');
    $(this).parent().next(".content").slideUp('slow');
});​
```

**Alternative select**

Note: If you are using jQuery 1.6.4, `closest()` method won't work.

```
$(".reveal").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".content").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: @ArtWorkAD i've updated my answer, according to your jsFiddle and if you want to do this with another way, you can inspect this accordion answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504193/collapse-and-expand-tabs-jquery-simple-accordion/11504398#11504398

Answer (score 3):

Simple :)

```
$("tr td.remove").live("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent("tr:first").hide('slow');
});

$(".reveal").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

It is better ti use .on() than live. it's preforms faster. like that:

```
$('table')
   .on('click','.reveal',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      //stuff
   }).on('click','.remove',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      //stuff
   });
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation() stops event click propagation on that element. very handy

Comment: I use jquery 1.6.2 and .on seems not to be support in this version.  Your first example is quite the same as my code, the e.stopPropagation makes no difference.

Comment: it was not working as soon as one of them was live, second was not... seems there is a conflict in such difference between clicks. and live click was triggered anyway. use live or click in both, then it's working.

Comment: Ok it works so far but there is a strange problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Wkh.png When I click on hide, sometimes it hides two columns at once. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: well :) i can only guess... maybe if you use my code... i have .next() without any selector inside, and if it does not have content after it, it will hide next row :)

Answer (score 1):

.on() has replaced .live(). On and hide don't work for you? They work just fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/Umxgy/

**EDIT**
Since you are using an older versin of jQuery, .live() is correct. Let me know if this works for you. I have a different selector than you do.

**EDIT 2**
Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Here is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Umxgy/2/

Comment: have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jVtC/1/ I want TWO actions "reveal" and "hide"

Comment: @ArtWorkAD What is it that you want to hide, and what is it that you want the event handler on? What is it that you want to show, and what is it that you want that event handler on?

Comment: Click on TR, reveal content below TR. Click on TD.remove within the SAME TR and hide the TR.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD If that is the case, do you really need the toggle on the whole tr, or just the first td? See my edit.