# jQuery accordion and jQuery mobile are not getting along really well

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using an accordion in one of my content pages. The style sheets and the jQuery source files are defined in the head section of the master page.

Now, in the master page I have included the jQuery mobile list view inside a div which is displayed when a media query for mobile phones is invoked.

Hence I have two pairs of jquery-ui and jquery-css source files: one for the jQuery mobile and one for the accordion.

The problem is, I cannot use both at the same time since they seem to conflict with each other. When one works, the other doesn't. Can someone help me out with a solution?

I tried with the noConflict method but that didn't help much. I could find only a few sources which were not really clear. Appreciate your help.

*P.S: I can provide you source code but it is kind of huge. It will take time to format it in a presentable way.*

Comment: you can build your own accordion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504193/collapse-and-expand-tabs-jquery-simple-accordion/11504398#11504398

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the JQuery UI accordion if you are using JQM? JQueryMobile allows you to create collapsible "accordion" style divs and group them together - see [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) for examples of how it works.