# How to identify active panel in accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery accordion in my coding.

I have 36 panels in an accordion with a form in each.

When I click the submit button I want to get what is in the input textboxes in the form of the open/active panel.

How to identify the open active panel in order to submit the relevant form?

Comment: inspect this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504193/collapse-and-expand-tabs-jquery-simple-accordion/11504398#11504398

Comment: can you give me more details 
$('span').click(function() {//close
   var takeID = $(this).attr('id').replace('Close','');//strip close from id
   $('#'+takeID+'C').slideUp(600);//hide clicked close button's panel

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="panel-header" data-panel-no="1">Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris 
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="panel-header" data-panel-no="2">Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>...
</div>
```

now with jquery onclick on class="panel-header" get the data-panel-no attribute value and store it in some temp variable.

```
var activePanel=-1;
$(function(){
   $(".panel-header").click(function()
    {
        activePanel = $(".panel-header").attr("data-panel-no").val();
    }
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how to show that the data-panel-no is open in order to show that there are values in the textboxes?

Comment: get the h3 where data-panel-no is equal to activePanel, then get the next sibling of h3 (using .next()) which is the <div> where your textboxes are

Answer (score 0):

Whenever i use javascript to do that kind of stuff, i add the class "active" to the current selected element.

```
$("a.navigation").click(function(e)
{
if($(this).is(".active")) return false;

$("a.navigation").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

That way it is always easy to detect what is activated and to act on it.

Comment: what is e attribute within the function?